# Getting data into a map

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I got my .dat data formatted into arrays I could use in graphs and whatnot.

I got my data from this website and it requires an account if you want to download it yourself. The data will still be provided below, however.

https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=1028

data in python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("ocean_flux_co2_2d.dat", header=None)
print(df.head())
```

---

```
        0     1         2         3
0 -178.75 -77.0  0.000003   32128.7
1 -176.25 -77.0  0.000599   32128.7
2 -173.75 -77.0  0.001649   39113.5
3 -171.25 -77.0  0.003838   58934.0
4 -168.75 -77.0  0.007192  179959.0
```

I then decided to put this data into arrays that could be put into graphs and other functions.

Like so:

```
lat = []
lon = []
sed = [] 
area = []
with open('/home/srowpie/SrowFinProj/Datas/ocean_flux_tss_2d.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(',')
        lat.append(float(parts[0]))       
        lon.append(float(parts[1])) 
        sed.append(float(parts[2]))
        area.append(float(parts[3]))

lat = np.array(lat)
lon = np.array(lon)
sed = np.array(sed)
area = np.array(area)
```

My question now is how can I put this data into a map with data points? Column 1 is latitude, Column 2 is longitude, Column 3 is sediment flux, and Column 4 is the area covered. Or do I have to bootleg it by making a graph that takes into account the variables lat, lon, and sed?

Comment: Do you want to plot the sed flux as color in the map, like a tiff file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the data into an array. Just apply `df.values` and you would have a `numpy` array of all the data in the dataframe.

Example -

```
array([[-1.78750e+02, -7.70000e+01,  3.00000e-06,  3.21287e+04],
       [-1.76250e+02, -7.70000e+01,  5.99000e-04,  3.21287e+04],
       [-1.73750e+02, -7.70000e+01,  1.64900e-03,  3.91135e+04],
       [-1.71250e+02, -7.70000e+01,  3.83800e-03,  5.89340e+04],
       [-1.68750e+02, -7.70000e+01,  7.19200e-03,  1.79959e+05]])
```

I'll not recommend storing individual columns as variable. Instead just set the column names for the dataframe and then use them to extract a `pandas` Series of the data in that column.

```
df.columns = ["Latitude", "Longitude", "Sediment Flux", "Area covered"]
```

This what the table would look like after this,

|  | Latitude | Longitude | Sediment Flux | Area covered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -178.75 | -77.0 | 3e-06 | 32128.7 |
| 1 | -176.25 | -77.0 | 0.000599 | 32128.7 |
| 2 | -173.75 | -77.0 | 0.001649 | 39113.5 |
| 3 | -171.25 | -77.0 | 0.003838 | 58934.0 |
| 4 | -168.75 | -77.0 | 0.007192 | 179959.0 |

Simply do `df[column_name]` to get the data in that column.
For example -> `df["Latitude"]`

Output -

```
0   -178.75
1   -176.25
2   -173.75
3   -171.25
4   -168.75
Name: Latitude, dtype: float64
```

---

Once you have done all this, you can use `folium` to plot the rows on real interactive maps.

```
import folium as fl

map = fl.Map(df.iloc[0, :2], zoom_start = 100)
for index in df.index:
  row = df.loc[index, :]
  fl.Marker(row[:2].values, f"{dict(row[2:])}").add_to(map)

map
```